# Setting up nginx for serving multiple side projects on a single domain, but without using sub-domains?

Tags: nginx, server

I want to build a portfolio site, which can showcase my side projects.
For example: I have domain "myportfolio.com"
So, I want my side projects to be served folder wise , like "myportfolio.com/project1", "myportfolio.com/project2"
The problem I face is that for each of the side project, the html files contains relative links to the assets required, so if I link the css file in the index.html file of Project 1 like this "/assets/style.css" , instead of fetching the file from "myportfolio.com/project1/assets/style.css", the browser fetched it from "myportfolio.com/assets/style.css".

That's the problem I am trying to solve.
I know his can be resolved using sub-domains, but I want to keep it easy for me to add new projects when ever i want and just add their alias in the nginx.conf file.

But the relative URL problem is being a roadblock from 2 days.

Comment: You might use the referer from the request and setup a condition with the if-Directive, what imho is a bad approach.
Or you better user relative paths instead of absolute ones. That's what they are made for

Comment: Can you explain a little more on relative and absolute paths, with an example please.

Comment: lets say you have an image "img1.png" referenced in test.com/project1/. <img src="/assets/img1.png"> would reference it absolute and letting the server search at http://test.com/assets/img1.png. Now you could change it to <img src="./assets/img1.png"> what will make the full path look like test.com/project1/assets/img1.png. The dot represents the current directory. More here: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/sharing_tools_and_toolboxes/pathnames_explained_colon_absolute_relative_unc_and_url.htm

Comment: Okay I got it, Thanks a lot for the time and help